# SQL - Is it good practice to include a lot of OR operators(like 1000 or more) to build follow system on my site?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a following system in my site. For example, a user follows 500 people and when that user goes to the main page, it will show messages that is posted from those 500 people. And I will make a query like:

```
SELECT UserComments FROM comments_table 
WHERE UserName = user1 OR user2 OR user3(...) 
ORDER BY PostDate DESC.
```

The problem is, I want to fetch comments from users that is followed, and I want to fetch them with `or` operator, but I have to include a lot of `or` operator in between of usernames. Is it good practice to add a lot of `or` operators?

What should I do? I'm using MYSQL.

Comment: You'd better use IN()

Comment: Do you have a table of users that each user follows? (Often called Junction Tables or Link Tables.)  You should only need to JOIN on to that table, rather than enumerating every link yourself.

Comment: `In()` has its place, however if you're looking at 1000+ potential conditions, you're usually much better off dumping these to a temp (or even permanent) table and joining against this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off storing these relationships in a table and joining to the table per user.

So you have a User table with an ID.  A Following table with LoggedInUserID and FollowedUserID.  Then join through the Following table to get comments.  Insert 1 record into Following for each User the LoggedInUser is following.  This way you keep track of the relationships between users and make good use of the indexes on these tables.

```
SELECT comments.UserComments FROM Following
INNER JOIN comments on comments.UserID = Following.FollowedUserID
WHERE Following.LoggedInUserID = UserID;
```

User

```
UserID  Field1    Field2
1       "Stuff"   "OtherStuff"
2       "More"    "Blah"
3       "And"     "Blerg"
```

Following

```
LoggedInUser    FollowedUserID
1               2
1               3
2               1
3               2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `IN` in this case:

```
SELECT UserComments FROM comments_table 
WHERE UserName IN (user1, user2, user3, .... userN) 
ORDER BY PostDate DESC
```

And many operators `OR` will bad affect on performance

Comment: I think joins are preferred over using in.

Comment: This is not performant, using joins makes better use of indexes and if done correctly will prevent table access on any table except the comment table.

Comment: @saarrrr Yes, but in the question I do not see other table, So I just try to help based on example from question